# How to get temporary password for Jenkins in google cloud

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

Below is screenshot of reference but not able to get exact what need to get temporary password from mention path.

These are guidelines given :

**Next steps**

Prerequisites
You'll need the following tools in your environment:

gcloud: if gcloud has not been configured yet, then configure gcloud by following the gcloud Quickstart.
kubectl: set kubectl to a specific cluster by following the steps at container get-credentials.
sed
Accessing your Jenkins instance
NOTE: For HTTPS, you must accept a temporary TLS certificate.

Read a temporary password:

```
$(kubectl -ndefault get pod -oname | sed -n /\\/jenkins-job-jenkins/s.pods\\?/..p) \
cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

Identify the HTTPS endpoint:

```
echo https://$(kubectl -ndefault get ingress -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=jenkins-job" -ojsonpath="{.items[0].status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}")/
```

Navigate to the endpoint.

Configuring your Jenkins instance
Follow the on-screen instructions to fully configure your Jenkins instance:

Install plugins
Create a first admin user
Set your Jenkins URL (you can choose to start with the default URL and change it later)
Start using your fresh Jenkins installation!
For further information, refer to the Jenkins website or this project GitHub page.
[image]

Comment: Did you navigate to the `/var/jenkins_home....` path and look for the file? I would `grep` the master for this file `initialAdminPassword`

Comment: I stuck don’t know how to connect to instance as per above description not able to get.

Comment: Oh! Are you are the jenkins server admin? You need to log into your `Kubernetes cluster` or `pod` and navigate to that path `/var/jenkins_home....` while your cluster is running. If you are not the admin, you need to talk to them.

Comment: Yes I am admin. I am new to all this. If you know some step explain me

Comment: I am not having visibility into your infrastructure and not much aware of google cloud, have you installed Kubernetes on `GCP Compute Engine` ? If yes you need to `SSH` into that GCE box and navigate to the path I suppose. Can you check these two links `https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-set-up-jenkins-on-kubernetes` and `https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/`

Answer (score 2):

I put a step by step instruction as follow:

- Under Kubernetes engine goto Workloads tab then on the right side click on your jenkins Stateful Set.
- You will route to the Stateful Set details page.
- Under Managed pods click on your pod name.
- On Pod details page you can find KUBECTL on the top right, Click on KUBECTL > Exec > jenkins-master
- Cloud shell terminal should open and two row of command will be paste into it.
- The very end of command should be ended with `jenkins-master -- ls`

Replace `ls` with `cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword` then press enter.

- Outcome will be your *Administrator password*, you may copy and paste it into "Unlock Jenkins" page!

Good luck!

Comment: How to connect to Jenkins ?

Comment: Ok, simply navigate to Kubernetes Engine > Services & Ingress then under SERVICE section find jenkins-[somethings]-ui which has external IP address. Click on external IP address and you will navigate to the Unlock Jenkins webpage. Paste your temporary password and continue the installation process.

Comment: Thank you so much for spelling this out!  Google's instructions were just a complete disaster.